# Telegram bot, TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token", parse_mode=None)
# @bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
# def send_welcome(message):
#   bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

print(bot.get_me())

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    if message.json['new_chat_participant']['id'] == 6390650589:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'всем приветик пистолетик я новенький')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    if message.chat.id == 1383954600 or message.chat.id == 1289518434:
        bot.send_message(-1001854224915, message.text)
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

```
bot.send_message(-1001854224915, message.text)
```

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Какое слово вам непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Когда копируешь код, бывает вместо отступов-табов проставляются просто пробелы. нужно вручную удалить все отступы и проставить их заново через кнопку TAB.

Comment: Наоборот, PEP 8 предписывает использовать 4 пробела для отступов

Comment: можно и пробелами, главное, чтобы везде были или табы, или пробелы. Ошибка дословно переводится:

`TabError: непоследовательное использование табуляции и пробелов в отступах`